# Add parent data object title to map() function SilverStripe

Tags: php, silverstripe

all I have one problem with setSource(Document::get()->map('ID', 'Title')) my client wants to Document be listed like breadcrumbs "Location Title -> Document Title", I was googleing hard and have no solutions with this, maybe any suggestions?

My documents has relation $has_one location and Locations $has_many Documents.

Answer (score 0):

try a getter method for Title:

```
public function getTitleForMap() {
    $parent =  ($this->ParentID) ? $$this->parent()->getTitleForMap() . ' > ';
    return $parent . $this->Title;
}
```

And use `Document::get()->map('ID', 'TitleForMap')` instead.